# Adobe e-book reader ("Digital Editions") not downloading on Mac OS X

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, ebook, drm

i recently bought a couple of books from ebooks.com, which i thought would be ordinary pdf files. After paying for them, and downloading them, you learn that while they are pdf files, they come with a lot of DRM baggage. The most conspicuous is that you can only view these files using an Adobe ebook reader called [Adobe Digital Editions](http://www.adobe.com/products/digitaleditions/). (Note: this is not the ordinary Adobe Acrobat Reader, or anything close--it's a dedicated app for reading DRM-laden files.

Fine--i'll know better next time. Still, i paid for these books and there's only one way i can actually read them, which happens to be an App that i seem to be unable to download. Here's the error message i get:

*"Couldn't write the application to the hard disk. Please verify the hard disk is available and try again"*

I've tried on several different browsers. My rig is a MBP, OS X 10.6.2. I've also checked the Adobe boards and this doesn't appear to be a known issue, nor could i find anything on their discussion forums. And just to be sure, i've checked my hard disk--no problems, plenty of space, and i have no problem, nor have i ever downloading other apps.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try with the [package installer](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/403/kb403051/attachments/digitaleditions_installer_x86.zip), not the flash installer ?